# Using "result" as a verb

Tags: prepositions, articles

Is the use of `results` in the sentence below correct? Should `higher quality` have article `the` or not?

> X results higher quality of products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say "results in". For example, "Better testing results in higher quality products."

If you want to use "of" for some reason, then "higher quality" becomes the object, and as it is singular, you need an article. "Better testing results in a higher quality of product." You'd normally use "a" and not "the" as we are talking about higher quality as a general attribute, not one particular higher quality.

Comment: Thanks. According to Longman, "result in" is using especially for something bad but "higher quality" is good. Are you sure it is good?

Comment: @BA I can think of no reason why *result in* would imply something bad. In fact, that makes little sense. On its own, it's neutral.  *A spur of the moment purchase resulted in my unexpected lottery win.* You can replace everything after *resulted in* with whatever you like.

Comment: I have routinely seen "result in" used with both positive and negative things. I don't know who "Longman" is but I think he is incorrect on this.

Comment: @Jay I mean this book: https://www.slideshare.net/ULIUniversalLanguage/longman-essay-activator-72982558

Comment: Well, it's possible that if you counted usages, you'd find that people use "result in" for something bad more often than for something good. He doesn't seem to give any discussion of this, just says "especially something bad". But it's commonly used for both good and bad, so I wouldn't even think about that when writing or speaking.